# Objective-C Charting Framework

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, frameworks, charts

I'm in urgent need of an Objective-C/Cocoa/Cocoa Touch framework to handle simple charting; pie chards, histograms etc.

The only thing that comes close is:

http://code.google.com/p/gchart-objc/

But it seems to be quite an early release and not maintained.

Has anyone created or used such a framework or library.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I use [Core Plot](https://github.com/core-plot/core-plot). See [this blog post](http://blogs.remobjects.com/blogs/mh/2010/01/26/p973) for a tutorial.

Comment: core plot is good. Moreover it is being actively developed, so you can actually get in touch with the developer and have issues addressed quickly.

Comment: Core Plot is an outstanding project. The past year I have faced the prospect that I was going to have to do all of this by hand. (I'm writing an application that compares metagenomic DNA sequences and graphs the results). Core Plot while still a small project currently fills a niche that I think is only going to grow, especially in the scientific community. List of blog posts on using it from their own wiki [here](http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/wiki/CorePlotOnTheWeb)

Answer (score 5):

I'll echo the suggestion of [core-plot](http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/), and add some additional plotting references that may be of interest:

http://cocoaheads.byu.edu/resources/plot

Answer (score 1):

you can have a look at [DSBarChart](http://dhilipsiva.github.io/DSBarChart/). It is a tiny library for creating Histograms.

Answer (score 0):

this is also a legend lib for charts : https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts