# Bar Chart in xcode

Tags: objective-c, xcode, graphing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Objective-C Charting Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2454302/objective-c-charting-framework)

Does anyone know how to draw graphs and bar charts in xcode?
Is it also possible to use data from an sqlite database to create these graphs?
Also can these be autoupdated when the database is changed.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Even though you don't specify it in your tags, it appears you're on iOS, so this question should also apply: [Is there a good charting library for iPhone?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/769749/is-there-a-good-charting-library-for-iphone).  As suggested in these questions, if you grab the Core Plot framework, look at the sample applications that come with it.  They show how to draw bar charts on Mac and iOS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those are 3 separate questions.

1. graphs and charts: try [Google Charts API](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/)
2. Yes, it is possible if you write the code to fetch the data and pass it to the graphing api.
3. Yes, they can if you write the right code to integrate the db changes to your view controllers.

Answer (score 2):

Try [CorePlot](https://github.com/core-plot), it has a lot of nice features and can draw different types of graphs.

Answer (score 0):

Try [DSBarChart](http://dhilipsiva.com/DSBarChart/).  It is created for this exact same purpose.