# Pie chart library

Tags: macos, cocoa, chat

Does anyone know how to make "pie chart" in a Cocoa application?

There are a few third party chat library for iOS but no library for Mac OS.

Does anyone have a suggestion?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Objective-C Charting Framework](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2454302/objective-c-charting-framework)

Answer (score 2):

Google's [Core Plot](http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/) graphing framework works on both Mac OS X and iOS.